# How to use Skimage to resize training data?

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn

I am trying to understand how the resize function in skimage works. I am trying to have my `x_train` data which is CIFAR10 dataset with the shape of `x_train shape: (50000, 32, 32, 3)` to be resized to (244, 244, 3) to be used in VGG19 model. I tried to using the following code to change the data, but am not sure if the results are correct as trying to do a plt.imshow(resized_xtrain[0]) gives me an odd image.

```
from skimage import transform
for i in range (50000):
    resized_xtrain= transform.resize(x_train[i], (224, 224, 3), order=1, mode='reflect')
```

When I do a `resized_xtrain.shape` I get a `(244, 244, 3)`. I am confused on how to set up this to have all 50,000 training images be resized and set to `resized_xtrain`. Basically how can I change the resize to put all of the training data into an array?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to index your `resized_xtrain`, do it like the following:

```
from skimage import transform

resized_xtrain = np.zeros((50000,224,224,3))
for i in range (50000):
    resized_xtrain[i] = transform.resize(x_train[i], (224, 224, 3), order=1, mode='reflect')
```

Comment: When doing this I receive a memory Error . Is there a way to get around this? I am using a school's server to access multiple GPUs